# Self-referencing nested functions in R?

Tags: r

So, I'm trying to write a function that builds a large complicated formula recursively. Basically, what I would love to work simply, is the following:

```
f <- function(x) {
  g <- function(y) y
  for( i in 1:4 ) {
    h <- g
    g <- function(y) h(y)^2
  }
  g(x)
}
```

Please refrain from laughing at this insane motivation. Now what I would like to get, is a function that returns ((((x^2)^2)^2)^2), but what actually happens is that my runtime just crashes immediately, probably because there's some sort of call to an unreferenced function or something, since I'm overwriting the expression for `g` every time (obviously I don't really know how r works in this scenario).

How can I achieve this idea of retaining the information from the older `g` references?

Comment: `h` isn't defined as one but is called as a function? Were you trying to assign the function `g` to `h` in that `h <- g` assignment?

Comment: Yeah, that's my logic behind that line. I'm trying to 'save' the information in the function g, and then use that old function to replace g with a new function, in this case with another iteration of squaring.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) Recursion** We can use recursion like this:

```
h1 <- function(f, n) if (n == 1) f else function(x) f(h1(f, n-1)(x))

# test using g from questioun
h1(g, 4)(3)
## [1] 43046721

(((3^2)^2)^2)^2
## [1] 43046721
```

**2) Reduce** This uses `Reduce` to compose a function `f` with itself iteratively `n` times.

```
h2 <- function(f, n) function(y) Reduce(function(x, f) f(x), rep(list(f), n), y)

h2(g, 4)(3)
## [1] 43046721
```

**3) for**

```
h3 <- function(f, n) {
  function(x) {
   for(i in 1:n) x <- f(x)
   x
  }
}

h3(g, 4)(3)
## [1] 43046721
```

**4) Fixed** If there are a small fixed number we could just write it out
explicitly:

```
h4 <- function(x) g(g(g(g(x))))

h4(3)
## [1] 43046721
```

**5) Compose**  We could slightly simplify any of the above using `Compose` from the functional package.  (The purrr package also has a `compose` function.  Use that if you are already using purrr; otherwise, functional has a smaller footprint.)

```
library(functional)

h1a <- function(f, n) if (n == 1) f else Compose(f, h(f, n-1))

h2a <- function(f, n) Reduce(Compose, rep(list(f), n))

h2b <- function(f, n) do.call(Compose, rep(list(f), n))

h3a <- function(f, n) {
  for(i in 1:n) ff <- if (i == 1) f else Compose(ff, f)
  ff
}

h4a <- Compose(g, g, g, g)
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I have yet to figure out how this will work in my use-case, but very informative nonetheless!